# Stop Cypress from doing BeforeEach() before every it

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

Right now I have:

```
describe("Multiple component test", () => {

it("tests first component", () => {
cy.get('selector').should('be.visible')
});

it("test second component", () => {
cy.get('selector').should('be.visible')
});

)};
```

However, my `beforeEach()` hook has a login and redirect flow so instead of just logging in once and going through the entire flow it logs in after every single part of the test i.e. it logs in between every `it`.

Is there a way to stop Cypress from running the `beforeEach()` hook between every single `it`? I want it to run once before the `describe` and that's it.

Comment: You can use `before()` instead of `beforeEach()`

Comment: @AlapanDas Thank you, I did that, but what happens now is that it clears my session after every `it`. So while on the UI it doesn't look like I'm logged out, as soon as it goes to another test, the web app returns an error that indicates I'm logged out. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `before()` instead of `beforeEach()` in combination with the added functionality in [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package and it solved my problem.